# Dancer::Tutorial connect to SQLite

Tags: perl, sqlite, dancer

I'm create database

```
sqlite3 database 
    create table if not exists entries (
        id integer primary key autoincrement,
        title string not null,
        text string not null
    );
    ^D
```

Where should i put this database ? 
After

```
  sub connect_db {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=".setting('database')) or
       die $DBI::errstr;

    return $dbh;
  }

  sub init_db {
    my $db = connect_db();
    my $schema = read_file('./schema.sql');
    $db->do($schema) or die $db->errstr;
  }

get '/' => sub {
    my $db = connect_db();
    my $sql = 'select id, title, text from entries order by id desc';
    my $sth = $db->prepare($sql) or die $db->errstr;
    $sth->execute or die $sth->errstr;
    template 'show_entries.tt', { 
       'msg' => get_flash(),
       'add_entry_url' => uri_for('/add'),
       'entries' => $sth->fetchall_hashref('id'),
    };
  };
```

Recieve an Error
Runtime Error
near "desk" : syntax error at /home/ultramozg/App/lib/App.pm line 40,  line 16

What it's my mistake ?

Comment: `desk` does not appear anywhere in what you presented. What's line 40 of lib/App.pm?

Comment: Line 40    my $sth = $db->prepare($sql) or die $db->errstr;

Comment: hum.... That doesn't sound like an error from DBI, but if you insist, what's in `$sql`?

Comment: Thanks but everything was decided.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you use Dancer::Plugin::Database instead of the connect_db routine you're proposing.  The way you're doing it will probably create leftover open connections and therefore all sorts of problems.  Dancer::Plugin::Database handles persistent connections for you.  Doc for plugin:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Database

Once you install Dancer::Plugin::Database and configure it in config.yml, then whenever you need to a database handle, you just:

```
my $dbh => database('my_database_name');
```

and don't bother disconnecting when done.

If you're using ubuntu, just:

```
apt-get install libdancer-plugin-database-perl
```

Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

You have a ^D character for starters - last line in the first section. Please learn to read output. It tells you line 16.

Check where the word "desk" appears in your code as well.

Comment: I create this database in terminal , ^D  = ctrl D

Comment: did u type the error out. Is it 'desk' or 'desc'

much easier to find errors with proper messages.

Comment: Thanks , database must be in the lib directory.